# PhoneGap-Plugin-Push or jQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to make ajax call to a php-file which saves registration-id of client. For this i use this javascript code:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: { senderID: "103232657886" },
        ios: { alert: "true", badge: "true", sound: "true" },
        windows: {}
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        $("#gcm_id").text(data.registrationId);

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://sebtm.lima-city.de/AT-GCM/insertRegistrationId.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {registrationId: data.registrationId},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
    });
}
```

};

Where MySenderId & MyUrl is a placeholder. The Registration ID is showen in #gcm_id but the ajax-call not working. How to debug this? How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved - the Ajax call worked fine - there was an error in the php-file.